# @code block not triggering on onclick event

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to get expanding menus working in Blazor, an example of why would be Reports or such, given that I may have multiple reports I want to hide the possibilities till I actively seek them out.

Using the stock template I added a onClick event to the NavMenu:

```
bool _expandScreen = false;

void ExpandScreens()
{
    if (_expandScreen)
    {
        _expandScreen = false;
    }
    _expandScreen = true;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

And the following html to below one of the menu items:

```
@if (_expandScreen)
{
    <NavLink class="expand-menu" href="">
       <span>Companies</span>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink class="" href="">
       <span>DIN</span>
    </NavLink>
}
```

When I debug, the breakpoint is never hit in the code block. The breakpoint against the html does, but as state of _expandScreens isn't updated it still evaluates to false.

I've checked the _imports.razor as suggested by another SO post. And my syntax appears to be correct according to examples within the app and that on msdn.

Anyone spot anything wrong with my code that I've missed?

EDIT: The complete code for NavMenu looks like this:

```html
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true" @onclick="ExpandScreens"></span> Screens
            </NavLink>
            @if (_expandScreen)
            {
                <NavLink class="expand-menu" href="">
                    <span>Companies</span>
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink class="" href="">
                    <span>DIN</span>
                </NavLink>
            }
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    bool _collapseNavMenu = true;
    bool _expandScreen = false;

    string NavMenuCssClass => _collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        _collapseNavMenu = !_collapseNavMenu;
    }

    void ExpandScreens()
    {
        if (_expandScreen)
        {
            _expandScreen = false;
        }
        _expandScreen = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't post the OnClick related code.

Comment: I realised and was updating the post just as you posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the `<span>` element the event handler is triggered.

I assume you just don't click it:

[image]

Try clicking the + sign and you will see that your menu is expanded.

Of course you can also attach the event handler to the parent element and event bubbling will take place.